# Fetch clause in JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to get value LEGAL_ENTITY_ID (Integer) from table for to use later.

```
 public static int fetchingLegalEntityId() {
    return DSL.using(connection).select(LEGAL_ENTITIES.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID)
            .from(LEGAL_ENTITIES)
            .where(LEGAL_ENTITIES.CODE.eq("someValue"))
            .fetchOne();      
}
```

but I have incompatible types.
What I need to do?

Comment: Or
  public static void fetchingLegalEntityId() {
        LegalEntitiesRecord record = DSL.using(connection).selectFrom(LEGAL_ENTITIES)
                .where(LEGAL_ENTITIES.CODE.eq(company))
                .fetchOne();
        legalEntityId = Optional.ofNullable(record).orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new).getLegalEntityId();
        LOG.info(String.format("LEGAL_ENTITY_ID is %d", legalEntityId));
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ResultQuery.fetchOne()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne()) produces a `Record`. [There are many many ways to fetch data in jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/the-many-different-ways-to-fetch-data-in-jooq/).

I could recommend various options, including:

- `fetchOptional().map(Record::value1).orElseThrow(...)`
- `fetchOne(LEGAL_ENTITIES.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID)`
- `DSLContext.fetchValue(select)`
- And many more

There isn't a best way to do such a query. Just explore the jOOQ API (e.g. by using an IDE and auto-completing your `fetch()` call to see what's available), and pick the style you prefer.